# Retrieve folder's name for Automator's shell script action

Tags: terminal, bash, automator, macos

For the sake of concatenating video files, I've assembled bits of code found online into a ffmpeg bash script on Automator. It works. However, I'd like for the output file to be named after the folder the videos are in.

I've found solutions online, but none of them follow a shell script workflow. My workflow is just (with an added demanded "Get Specified Finder Items" when tested within Automator):

```
current_path=$(dirname "$1")
cd "$current_path"

for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1/bin/ffmpeg -i concat:"$(pipeize() { local OLDIFS="$IFS";IFS='|';echo "$*";IFS="$OLDIFS";}; pipeize *.VOB)" -c copy -map "0:v?" -map "0:a?" -map "0:s?" "THIS_SHOULD_BE_THE_DIRECTORY_NAME.VOB"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `$1` is e.g. `"/path/to/filename.VOB"` so `$current_path` would be: `/path/to`

So, for `$filename` use `filename="$(basename "$current_path")"` placed after: `current_path="$(dirname "$1")"` and then `ext=".VOB"` afterwards. You can then change `.VOB` to other extensions as needed.

Thus, change `"THIS_SHOULD_BE_THE_DIRECTORY_NAME.VOB"` to `"${filename}${ext}"` as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_path="$(dirname "$1")"
filename="$(basename "$current_path")"
ext=".VOB"
cd "$current_path"

for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1/bin/ffmpeg -i concat:"$(pipeize() { local OLDIFS="$IFS";IFS='|';echo "$*";IFS="$OLDIFS";}; pipeize *.VOB)" -c copy -map "0:v?" -map "0:a?" -map "0:s?" "${filename}${ext}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works, although I believe you missed a `"` on `filename="$(basename "$current_path")".VOB"`, as the script only runs on my end if I add one. Do you know how I could modify the code so that it works with any extension? I tried a bunch of workflows and edits to the code, but they all fail in different ways. I'm interested on using the same action for folders which may contain .VOB, or .m2ts, or .mkv.

Comment: @firewater, I've updated the answer to address your comment, making a separate variable for the filename and extension. I do believe what I've added is quoted properly, as I've double checked it at [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). That said, your code throws some flags, so I'd suggest you use ShellCheck to see what's up.